# GPSD cant get RTK when using a laptop

Tags: gps, gpsd

When I connect an antenna and its receiver via usb to my desktop computer I get RTK pretty quickly.
But if I do so on a laptop (ThinkBook 15p imh) it takes a long time to get just above 2D Mode and it will never get better than status fix.

For analysis I used cpgs and my own gpsd client written in c. I also tried the c++ version.
I just use the example code from:
https://gpsd.io/client-howto.html
It seems to display the same data as cgps.
So I think my testing setup is just fine.
But again, if I run the setup in the same location on the same machine but without a power plug its throtteling a lot.
I am running ubuntu 20.04.
Heres my config to run the gpsd service:
`DEVICES="/dev/ttyACM1"

GPSD_OPTIONS="-n -F /run/gpsd.sock ntrip://u_name:pw@openservice-sapos.niedersachsen.de:2101/mounting_point

USBAUTO="true"

START_DAEMON="true"
`

I censored the ntrip data and yes the serial port is correct.
Restarting and disconnecting the usb plug also doesnt help it.

Maybe someone is experienced in this field and can help me out :).
Thanks in advance, Eric.